# what today's numbers are yesterday meaning

Tags: meaning

I am reading a book about project management and there it said

> Business leaders are going to want to know what today’s numbers are yesterday. And they probably want to know what tomorrow’s sales figures are going to be yesterday as well.

I don't understand *what today's numbers are yesterday* means and what *what tomorrow's sales figures are going to be yesterday* means.

Comment: If the sentence is `Business leaders are going to want to know what today’s numbers are. They probably want to know what tomorrow’s sales figures are going to be.`, it makes sense that they have to look ahead for new opportunity. But I don't understand why the word `yesterday`is there. Is it even right in syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author could mean they must be able to see into the future.

Yesterday, they needed to know what will happen today and tomorrow. Today is too late: they wanted the information yesterday.

Similarly they don't want today's sales figures today, but need to know what will happen tomorrow, because they are managers. Will they need extra staff to cope with demand, and will they run out of stock?

---

Or, they could be talking about the high-pressure working environment in a business. Associated with this use of 'yesterday' is the idiom

> I need this done by yesterday!

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/need+(something)+yesterday). Here, it means *immediately* or *as soon as possible*.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clear explanation!